# What size power supply would I need for a computer with these specifications?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I'm building a computer with the following specifications, but I'm not sure if my 430-watt power supply is sufficient.

- AMD Phenom x4 9600
- Gigabyte Motherboard[GA-MA785GM-US2H](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=3141)
- [4 gigs of OCZ](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=3404049&Sku=O261-8038)
- 1 dvd/cdrw drive
- 2-3 hard drives
- Fan header

What would be the minimum size of a power supply that I would need to safely run this computer?

**Update**
I measured how many watts my computer is using and it's around 99-150 watts on average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use a dedicated video card a 350W PSU (from a good brand) sould be sufficient.
If you use a dedicated video card depend on his consumption.

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient as long as you don't forgot to mention one (or more) high-end graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool to calculate the PSU size

http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Follow your motherboard's [Users Manual](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/Manual_Model.aspx?ProductID=3141) which recommends a 500 W or greater power supply on page 24. 430 W is not even close.

Also, you need a 24-pin motherboard power connector and an 8-pin processor power connector. It is unlikely that a 430 W power supply will have the 8-pin processor power connector.

By the way, my quick, and very conservative calculations (*not* using the calculator in the other answer) are about 150 Wmax for everything but the motherboard. The motherboard itself can easily be a few hundred W.